Ireshark -Display Filter to Show Packet # in "gtpv2.response_to" Header
Using WS 4.2.5
I am looking at gtpv2 traffic.
Looking for some kind of display logic that is something like "If gtpv2.cuase==73, display that packet and the packet indicated in gtpv2.response_to header."
The ultimate goal is to display CREATE SESSION REQUESTS and their correlating CREATE SESSION RESPONSE  messages, when the CSResp has gtpv2.cause==73.  When I have close to a million packets to sift through, it is taking me a long time to filter through manually this way.
I set columns for "gtpv2.response_in" and "gtpv2.response_to", but I cannot figure out how to set a display filter that references a packet number that is displayed in the decoded info.

Have a look at Wireshark's MATE feature.
What is MATE? To quote from the Introduction, "... with MATE you can create user configurable extension(s) of the display filter engine."
